# How to implement search modes in Android Search Bar pattern?

Tags: android, android-widget, uisearchbar

Android Search Bar pattern has a search mode selection drop down. Can anybody tell me how is it implemented? Any pointers to source code/examples would be great.
I want code that works on Android 2.2+ devices.

[image: Android Search Bar with search modes]

Comment: means you want to implement that "Tweets, people" bar below?

Comment: yes. exactly. It should be hidden until clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then check this example [How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) and implement the same on your button click.

Answer (score 1):

The Greendroid library has [Quick Actions](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=347).